# How to flash bios of Asus Aspire laptop without using windows?

Tags: laptop, bios, flash, acer-aspire, firmware

My laptop (Acer Aspire 6530G) screen stays black, I try to update the firmware, maybe it helps. So I downloaded the latest firmware from [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/de/DE/content/support-product/567?b=1), it is a .exe file.

But how can I trigger the flash without entering windows?

I've read [here](http://techniciansguides.blogspot.com/2009/06/are-you-one-of-plenty-aspire-one-user.html) that if you hold down the key <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then press the start button and still hold it, then the power button starts to blink. Can I just enter the USB stick and try this ?

Update:
The screen stays black, nothing is visible at all.

Comment: Flashing your firmware is unlikely going to fix your display issue

Comment: According to the article I posted, it does.

Comment: Your original link was in German.

Comment: Make a WinPE LiveUSB and boot from it, then execute the BIOS flashing from there.

Comment: @K7AAY, do I need to see something to do this? As I said the display stays black

Comment: Is it black when, shortly after power up, it runs a Power On Self Test and opens the BIOS/firmware, waiting for you to interrupt it for the purpose of editing same? Also, please respond by clicking [edit] and updating the question with the requested data instead of using _Add Comment_ as, when comments pile up, new comments can push old comments off screen. Your findings should go in the Question where all may see them; our questions are less important.